# how to get specific key/value from the dictionary using python?

Tags: python

**how to tweak certain data** in this dictionary, I can only show them all but not able to select values for example lowest performer from the staff.

```
  staff = {
    'Williams': {
        'position': 'marketing',
        'performance': 71
    },
    'Kelly': {
        'position': 'marketing',
        'performance': 65
    },
    'Johnson': {
        'position': 'marketing',
        'performance': 49
    },
    'Thompson': {
        'position': 'marketing',
        'performance': 53
    }
}

for key, value in staff.items():
        print('The employee', key, 'is recommended for dismissal')

        for k, v in value.items():
                 print(v)
```

this is the output:

```
The employee Williams is recommended for dismissal
marketing
71
The employee Kelly is recommended for dismissal
marketing
65
The employee Johnson is recommended for dismissal
marketing
49
The employee Thompson is recommended for dismissal
marketing
53
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. In general, there is plenty of info about dictionaries and how to use them online. if you are having trouble with a specific concept, you should explain what you are having trouble with so we could help.

Comment: it is already highlighted in the description, is it still not specific?

Comment: Not really, no. first you ask in the title how to get a key/value from dictionary, then you ask in the question how to tweak it (not sure what that means). then you provide code that clearly shows that you do know how to access keys and values in the dictionary. so what is the question? If you read the link I sent you you will understand how to ask in a way that will get you better answers. Anyway... I'm pretty sure a quick dictionary tutorial such as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) will answer all your questions. you can easily google it.

Comment: tweak means to pull something from the list, so my question is constructed into "how to get specific key/value " because I don't want to print all the data.

Comment: There is no `list` in your code. There is a `dictionary`. If you want to learn how to use a `dictionary`, I have sent you a link for a tutorial. If you want to ask a good question, read the post about how to do that, and then ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the lowest performer from the staff, you may use the following code:

`sorted(staff.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['performance'])[0]`

It sorts the dictionary by the `performance` and shows the first result

Comment: hi , thank you but may i know where should I put that?

Comment: Wherever you need. If you want to print the lowest performer, just write `print(sorted(staff.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['performance'])[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You can always write code to do it, however there are no functions to do it.
You may create another dictionary for holding the lowest, highest or the item you want.

Comment: the output must show the lowest performer, I cant do another dictionary of course just to adjust the output. that is why I'm asking what may be the possible function to do it